# How can I start usb_modeswitch before the network-configuration?

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, raspbian, usb-modem

I'm using a Huawei E3531 to connect a Raspberry Zero running on vanilla Raspbian 8.0 (jessie) to the internet. As this is for a remote standalone application, it needs to be able to automatically get back online after a power-blackout.

I've configured usb_modeswitch to switch the USB-mode to cdc_ether, which reliably brings up an eth0 after the modeswitch. Unfortunately usb_modeswitch is started **after** the network devices are configured, therefore the network-link is not brought up on a cold boot (It works nicely on a reboot, where the mode is already correctly set).

According to https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/ it should be possible to add *network-pre.target*-directives to a service to get it to run before the network is configured:

> network-pre.target is a target that may be used to order services 
>       before any network interface is configured.
>       It's primary purpose is for usage with firewall services that want
>       to establish a firewall before any network interface is up.
>
> It's a passive unit: you cannot start it directly and it is not pulled
>       in by the the network management service, but by the service that 
>       wants to run before it. 
>       [..]
>       Services that want to be run before the network is configured 
>       should place Before=network-pre.target and also set Wants=network-pre.target 
>       to pull it in. 
>       This way, unless there's actually a service that needs to be ordered 
>       before the network is up the target is not pulled in, hence avoiding 
>       any unnecessary synchronization point.

I've modified ***/var/lib/systemd/system/usb_modeswitch@.service*** and added ***Before-/Wants***-directives accordingly:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB_ModeSwitch
Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch_dispatcher --switch-systemd %I
Environment="TMPDIR=/run"
```

Which now leads to a "Ordering cycle" error on booting:

```
[..]
[  OK  ] Started Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping LSB: Raise network interfaces.
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping Network (Pre)
[  OK  ] Created slice system-usb_modeswitch.slice.
[..]
```

Here's the output of *systemctl show ..*:

```
root@raspberrypi:/lib/systemd/system# systemctl show -p Requires,Wants,Requisite,BindsTo,PartOf,Before,After usb_modeswitch@.
Requires=basic.target
Requisite=
Wants=network-pre.target system-usb_modeswitch.slice
BindsTo=
PartOf=
Before=network-pre.target shutdown.target
After=systemd-journald.socket basic.target system-usb_modeswitch.slice

root@raspberrypi:/lib/systemd/system# systemctl show -p Requires,Wants,Requisite,BindsTo,PartOf,Before,After usb_modeswitch@.service
Failed to get properties: Unit name usb_modeswitch@.service is not valid.
root@raspberrypi:/lib/systemd/system#
```

I'm also wondering why *systemctl show* works with *usb_modeswitch@.* but not with *usb_modeswitch@.service*

Removing the two lines in the service-file restores the old behaviour without SKIP-errors.

Is there any other way to bring up the network-interfaces after the usb_modeswitch? Do I need to adapt anything else in the systemd-configuration to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to fix the issue using the following configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB_ModeSwitch
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target systemd-sysctl.service
Before=network-pre.target shutdown.target
Wants=network-pre.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch_dispatcher --switch-systemd %I
Environment="TMPDIR=/run"
```

I found the solution via [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shorewall/+bug/1511869/comments/3) on an Ubuntu-bugreport, which refers to a similar problem with shorewall instead of usb_modeswitch.

*DefaultDependencies* [is defined as](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html#):

> will implicitly complement all configured dependencies of type Wants= or Requires= with dependencies of type After=

I have not tested if this setting is a key part of the configuration or if it can be left out.

--

Here's the full explanation from the aforementioned bug-report (For shorewall instead of usb_modeswitch):

> Shorewall does not come with a systemd native service unit description. Such description is being generated at boot by /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-sysv-generator based on /etc/init.d/shorewall. I have noticed, however, that the LSB header of /etc/init.d/shorewall wants the service to be started from /etc/rcS.d, which is pretty early, and at the same time it has Required-Start: $network $remote_fs, which is a pretty strong requirement. In fact, this is the only script in /etc/rcS.d that requires $network (well, except shorewall6, which exhibits exactly the same problem). Looking into the auto-generated unit in /run/systemd/generator.late/shorewall.service shows:

```
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sysinit.target shutdown.target
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target
Wants=network-online.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
```

> This looks problematic: sysinit.target is a very early target, most higher level services are started after it, and on many systems (including mine) various dependencies will make network-online.target available only after sysinit.target.

Whatever the exact cause was, this configuration works for me and doesn't seem to have any undesired effects.